# How to set status bar for a section on scroll view page

Tags: javascript, react-native, statusbar

On my home page there are 3 sections. 
1st image section
2nd content
3rd content

when I scroll page after image section, there should be status bar for 2nd and 3rd sections.

how do i visible the status bar when I scroll the page?

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

render() {
    return(
          <View>
             <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
               <View>
                 <Image/>
               </View>
               <View>
                  <Text/>
               </View>
               <View>
                   <Text/>
               </View>
             </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          </View>
)}
```

Should be visible status bar after scrolling image section

Comment: its hard to find on google

Comment: Maybe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-2n01y?fontsize=14) will help you get started

Comment: Finally did this referring below article . https://medium.com/@habibridho/implementing-collapsing-toolbar-using-react-native-4a84e1718f11

Comment: Glad you got it working :)